How critical is memory in achieving proficiency at Master's and PhD levels in mathematics?
How significant is memory in excelling in higher-level mathematics, particularly at the Master's and PhD levels?
I sometimes have trouble remembering certain theorems, proofs, and conclusions. However, when I had time to look at the book and my own notes, I was able to solve problems effectively.
What is the real need for memorization in mathematics? Is the ability to recall mathematical concepts from memory the key to achieving proficiency, OR is understanding and application, supported by reference material, sufficient?

It's very similar to language. Having a good memory for words certainly makes some things easier, but it does not replace understanding of the grammar. Develop both.

To do research you generally need to remember a theorem exist, not the theorem (you can always look it up). So I'd say memory is very important, memorization is not. I always say I am well happy to return my PhD if the internet ceases to exist.

I have a few time-tested books that contain lots of useful stuff. I know which book, and vaguely where in it even without the index. The books are much better at remembering details than I am.

I don't think it's likely you're going to get a good answer to this question here. It's effectively a research question that only experiments could answer.

In case it helps you, here’s a more or less relevant real-world example. During my Ph.D. thesis defense, when answering a question from one of my committee members (i.e., judges). I drew a complete blank on the term Gaussian elimination. I wanted to use it, but couldn’t remember it! After observing a few seconds of my stammering, they invited me to merely describe what it meant. I did so, and they rewarded me with a reminder of what the term was. And, shortly thereafter, with a decision to grant me the degree.

I find the question somewhat unclear since you do not specify what you mean by "memorization". Do you mean something like rote learning definition, theorems, arguments? In this case the answer is: you essentially don't need it at all. On the other hand, if you work a lot with some definitions, theorems, and arguments, you will automatically remember them later (most likely not all the details, but the main insights and ideas and techniques, which is precisely what you would like to remember).

‘[But] when I had time to look at the book and my own notes, I was able to solve problems effectively.’ Memorization is part of your  essential cognitive development. You’ll find a large part of research mathematics is identifying and formulating problems to solve.

Real proficiency in math requires memory, yes, but it goes beyond that. Memory is good for the details, but what is really required is insight. And to develop insight you need to spend time on the details and employ memory, though not always memory of specific facts.
Memory is enough to let you know what is already known, but a real mathematician needs more. It is the ability to imagine what might be true and worth exploring that separates the merely competent from the true mathematician. Good doctoral advisors likely have this insight, but a doctoral degree in itself may not be enough.
The brain is a complex thing. Quick recall is a benefit, but not strictly essential for someone with insight, as the details are probably easy to find if one has a "sense" that they exist.
For most people, achieving mastery requires a lot of repetition. Solving a lot of problems, for example. The way the brain works, this repetition will increase the likelihood that things are required. But when one moves on to study new things, those remembered facts get pushed to the background to some extent - more for some than others. And most of us need to be reminded of some things, at least occasionally. But, hopefully, that repetition will lead to insight, which is the key.


OR is understanding and application, supported by reference material, sufficient?

I am assuming you mean pure maths ("PhD in mathematics") and in the US context. Well, the strictest answer here is "no it is not sufficient" because to pass your PhD qualifying exam in the US, you are essentially thrown "hard" graduate level questions at you, where you are supposed to be able to recall theorems and apply them without help. This is a syllabus for Stanford's geometry exam -- pretty much you need to memorize lots of concepts from the syllabus to have a good chance of passing.
While the qualifying exam is "just an exam", it is a notable barrier to doing research in the mathematics.

Is the ability to recall mathematical concepts from memory the key to achieving proficiency

Not that much. It really depends on how far you have mastered the materials. See related writings by Terence Tao maybe?

Concepts overlap, very often new ideas come from the fact that someone realized that X concepts can merge and give something new (I am simplifying here, but you get the idea). If you can't recall concepts from memory, this does not make the whole thing impossible, but harder and probably longer.
Even though, you don't need to memorize every concepts perfectly, very often just knowing that it exists is enough to make a link.
But I suspect this question is not for this Stack, maybe Philosophy of Math, if such stack exists.

It varies from case to case as you might not need to memorize the theorems but you need to remember the steps. There is a subtle difference between remembering and memorization as the former is used in a bit vague sense. People in medical and pharmacy need to learn tons of difficult jargons and especially for non-English speaker (maybe for English speakers too), it is a nightmare. Even in Maths, you need to remember the steps and not memorize them. And remember would come with effective understanding of the problem be it theorem, derivation or conclusion. Unfortunately, there are both merits and demerits of both of them. Explaining them would take a major portion of the space, so I skip that part.
Regardless of pros and cons, I would urge you to adopt a bit change in your learning habits. Firstly, try to understand what you are doing because when you understand things, automatically you will do it without remembering. You can job down different steps and try to make connections between them.
Secondly, if understanding is not solving your problem, try to breakdown a large task to multiple small tasks. For instance you can split a large theorem or derivation to smaller and easier to grasp chunks. Master the smaller chunks and connect the dots to complete the picture.
Hope it helps!
